# Pasar de un fragment a otro a traves de un boton

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenas tengo Navegation Drawer dentro de ello tengo un fragment que se activa cuando pulso en galería(que esta en la barra deslizante por defecto),dentro de ese fragment tengo un botón, mi pregunta es, como puedo mostrar otro fragment nuevo pulsando ese boton(ojo: el boton esta dentro del fragment). no se si me explique bien

este boton con id `btneditperf` esta en mi fragment y para que funcione los botones osea unirlos con una variable hize con el View

```
View rootView;
Button btneditperf;
-----------------
btneditperf = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btneditperf);
------------------
```

Intente con lo siguiente pero mi aplicacion se detiene

```
btneditperf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment nuevoFragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_perfil, nuevoFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Veo que realizas varias preguntas de este tipo, recuerda que es importante agregar un [mcve], que has intentado? comparte tu código.

Comment: ;D esque estoy por acabar el ciclo de la uni :v, y llevo dias sin dormir :( , esoty metido en esto porque mi android lo estoy haciendo con firebase es sobre un juego de matematicas
ya acutalize la pregunta

Comment: Hola @kevvelas aquí es el sitio indicado para apoyarte en la realización de proyectos, solo debes realizar correctamente las preguntas, agrega código, imágenes de lo que deseas y realiza tu pregunta en base a [ask], con esto obtendrás muy buenas respuestas.

Comment: ok, gracias por el dato

Comment: OK @kevvelas , "se detiene" pero revisa ahora el LogCat y agrega que mensaje se muestra dentro del mismo, busca "Caused by....."

Comment: aparece esto

MenuActivity es el nombre del NavegationDrawer el fragment donde estoy se llama PerfilFragment y adonde quiero ir cuando pulse el boton se llama BlanckFragment

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.MenuActivity@28ef53d4 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                                                at com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.BlankFragment.onAttach(BlankFragment.java:83)

Comment: El error ocurrio en BlakFragment linea 83 pero no tienes esa clase en la pregunta, te sugiero agregar esa información.

Comment: bueno, ese onAttach se genera automaticamente cuando se crea un fragment

Comment: Estas hablando de algo que no conocemos @kevvekas porque no agregas esa información en tu pregunta y en base a eso se puede determinar de mejor forma el problemas.

Comment: bueno, ya me rendi, la cosa solo era por diseño, en ves de fragment ahora lo estoy pasando a un activity, les dejo el codigo para los que no sepan
btneditperf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NombredelActivityadondequieresIr.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

Comment: Te rindes fácil amigo jaja después encontraras problemas mas grandes ... debes ser persistente y así también podrás aprender cosas nuevas

Comment: jejeje, bueno hay que buscar otras soluciones mas practicas y no estancarse en un problema xd

Comment: los fragmentos son bastantes utiles ... aveces tener solo una actividad y utilizar fragment's es mas util. bueno depende también de tus requerimientos funcionales y no funcionales ..